# I get the "SC OpenService Failed Access is denied" error when using an sc config command.

Tags: command-line, windows-8.1, cmd.exe, administrator

[image: Here is a snapshot of the cmd session]

I am already running cmd.exe with the highest privilege. Why am I still denied access?

Other commands like sc queryex works just fine.

[image]

I have not tried using the sc config on other services yet. Didn't want to mess too much with things when I don't yet know what's going on.

I am running Windows Version 6.3.9600 (Windows 8.1)

Comment: Although probably not applicable here, some applications lock the service manager. Process Explorer is one such application. I don't know what operations this interferes with, aside from service creation and deletion.

Answer (score 2):

The Task Scheduler is an essential system component and as such is protected
from some manipulations.

I do not understand why it is necessary to configure it for auto-start.
It should already be set this way. The fact that you are having troubles
configuring it means that it is already running.

If you are just practicing on using the `sc config` command, I suggest trying
it on a less important service. Verify by
opening the Services applet, right-click the service and check that not all actions
are grayed-out.

Although not recommended,
[this thread](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsserver/en-US/b9e5a4c0-073c-42fd-a390-8b2aee407a4f/task-scheduler-service-schedule-cannot-be-stopped-in-windows-2008-r1-?forum=winserversecurity)
has an answer on how to disable such a service so it may be configured.
I do not recommend it, as Windows boot might malfunction.

Answer (score 0):

#### "SC OpenService Failed Access is denied" error when using an sc config command.

Looking at your second screenshot, it looks like you are trying to change the configuration of a running service.

Try stopping the service first and then restarting it after you have changed the configuration.

> Some options only take effect at the point when the service is started e.g. the SC config command allows the executable of a service to be changed. When the service next starts up it will run the new executable. Config changes requires the current user to have “permission to configure the service”.

Source [SC - Service Control - Windows CMD - SS64.com](https://ss64.com/nt/sc.html)

Comment: One problem : The Task Scheduler cannot be stopped - if you right-click it in the Services applet you will see that all actions are grayed-out.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Windows protects some services configuration from changes. It doesn't matter whether the service is running or not. I tried disabling Windows Store service and failed the same way:

```
sc config WSService start=disabled
Access is denied.
```

But at the same time I could do it by editing registry:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\ControlSet001\Services\WSService\Start=4
```